# Having same commands in different Emacs configuration files.

Tags: customize, config

I am using Prelude Emacs and it has different configuration files. I keep my configuration files inside `~/.emacs.d/personal/`. . Say,  I have a command `(menu-bar-mode 1)` that enables menu bar inside `config1.el`  but later I unintentionally put another command in another configuration file `config2.el` in which there ise `(menu-bar-mode 0)` that disables menu bar of emacs. Which configuration file overtakes other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of sexp (S-expression - it's not a command), the last one that is evaluated is the one that "wins".

Comment: Is there a way of knowing repeated S-expression in different `el` files? and what is the command of knowing the order of directories loaded in emacs? How do I know that which `el` file is evaluated last? Is it according to alphabetical order of file name?

Comment: I don't understand your questions in the comment. I suggest that you formulate separate clear questions for them.